# Getting AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT in aql while trying to connect to a host with docker

Tags: docker, aerospike, aql

Recently when I am trying to connect to aerospike server using the docker command with username and password it consistently fails by throwing an error :

> WARN Failed to connect to seed a.b.c.d port number.
>   AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT  from a.b.c.d:port number Error 9: Failed to
>   connect .

I am trying to execute the command in PowerShell.
Below is the command.

```
docker run -ti --name test --rm aerospike/aerospike-tools aql -h a.b.c.d -U xyz(username) -P asdfghijk(password)
```

Comment: Where did you get this IP from ? My guess at this point is that you are using container private ip. It won’t work unless you link the tools container with server container.

Comment: This is the i.p of the database server.

Comment: Yes, but where did you get this from ?